# Android Rating Bar layout weight property not behaving properly

Tags: android, ratingbar

I have a `TextView` and `RatingBar` in `LinearLayout` with horizontal oriantation.

I want to set `TextView`in left most area and `RatingBar` in right most area. So I give the `LinearLayout`a weight sum along with this two views so that later I can give them `layout_gravity` `left` and `end`.

But the problem is when I am giving rating bar `layout_weight` it is increasing or decreasing its rating bar number. I've set rating bar number fixed but still it's not working. So how can I set `layout_weight` for `RatingBar`?

**My code:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Service"/>
        <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rbAddFoodItemRatingDialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:max="5"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
        android:rating="3.5"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This XML layout giving me 7 rating bar instead of 5 bar! What's wrong with this?

Comment: Wrap it in a linearlayout and set weight to that?

Comment: yeah I solved it by doing this . Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in a linearlayout and set weight to that

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Service"/>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="7">

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rbAddFoodItemRatingDialog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:max="5"
            android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
            android:rating="3.5"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```